# How to set marker on particular date in Tapku calender

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, tapku

In my application i use Tapku calendar to display a date in calender.

I want to display particular date in calendar like,

I have date 2012-11-01 than Marker comes on 2012-11-01 in calender.

Please suggest me How can i do that with Tapku caleder.

Answer (score 0):

```
     - (NSArray*) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate*)startDate toDate:(NSDate*)lastDate
    {
            [self generateRandomDataForStartDate:startDate endDate:lastDate];
            return dataArray;
    }


- (void) generateRandomDataForStartDate:(NSDate*)start endDate:(NSDate*)end{
    // this function sets up dataArray & dataDictionary
    // dataArray: has boolean markers for each day to pass to the calendar view (via the delegate function)
    // dataDictionary: has items that are associated with date keys (for tableview)


    NSLog(@"Delegate Range: %@ %@ %d",start,end,[start daysBetweenDate:end]);

    self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSDate *d = start;
    while(YES){

        int r = arc4random();
        if(r % 3==1){
            [self.dataDictionary setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item one",@"Item two",nil] forKey:d];
            [self.dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

        }else if(r%4==1){
            [self.dataDictionary setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Item one",nil] forKey:d];
            [self.dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

        }else
            [self.dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];


        TKDateInformation info = [d dateInformationWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        info.day++;
        d = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
        if([d compare:end]==NSOrderedDescending) break;
    }

}
```